Does a decision usually take this long after submitting for peer review? It's been over a week and the editor was assigned within a day of submission
I am a newbie to the peer review process, but the first journal I submitted to responded with a decision from the editor in chief within about 5 days after i resubmitted after It was initially sent back for revision (formatting errors). "We are sorry to inform you that your manuscript was rejected for publication blah blah blah, while we appreciate your contributions, the manuscript does not closely align with the scope of the journal, and the reason for the rapid decision is to allow you to submit your manuscript  to other journals in a timely fashion" (your manuscript sucks, so no dice). That wasn't that big of a surprise given that the first journal is pretty prestigious and has an average acceptance rate of 5 to 10%, vs an estimated 15 to 35% for the journal I recently submitted to. The current journals scope is more in line with my research interests and has a few publications covering my topic in other aspects. I honestly expected to have to go through a few rejections from multiple reputable journals, given that I have never submitted for peer review and my only experience with research/ scholarly communication is presenting at my institutions annual research symposium and a research conference up state focused on undergraduate scholarship earlier this year. So maybe this means it won't be outright rejected?
I would have expected a decision or update from the editor by now, I know the peer review process isn't quick and usually takes months, but it was my understanding that the editor in chief or senior editor sends out a decision or comments fairly quickly (within about 12 days), especially considering that the editor was assigned within about 30 hours of submission, alongside the fact that this journal publishes often. My current status is "under review" and has been that way since the second day of my submission
Should I contact the journal If I don't get any update within 4 weeks or so? Do editors ever just forget about a manuscript/ ignore them? I know I'm being a bit too eager/ impatient, but I was hoping to share this accomplishment with my college peers and my supervisor/ mentors back at college before I start my next degree in the fall of 2025 and we lose contact.
I'd appreciate some insight, thanks in advance.

"I know I'm being a bit too eager" It seems like you already know the answer.

@morxa fair enough.

The editor will only filter out "obviously bad" papers. All others go for review. Reviewers often get told a >=6 weeks deadline, which many reviewers miss, sometimes by months. "Under review" is the status you are hoping for 12 days after submission. Depending on the field, it can easily take 6 months before you hear back. The editor will often send a decision quite quickly (after less than a month) after receiving the reviews.

6 weeks sounds like a dream to me. I have a paper that recently celebrated 2 years since submission, still under review.
